# Database doesn't updating by 1

Tags: php, sql, increment

I tried to make a like button which will update the database table incremented by one but something isn't right, its updating by `'+34'` someone knows whats the problem ? here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
    $like = (int) $_POST['like'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `kladilnica` SET Liked = Liked+1 WHERE ticket_id = '".$like."' AND Username = '".$user."'";
    $return = $conn->query($sql);
    $responseText = ($conn->affected_rows) 
    ? "<li class='SuccShared' id='activator'>You have successfully shared the ticket $ticket_id</li>" 
    : "<li class='AlreadyShared' id='activator'>The ticket ($ticket_id) was shared already</li>";
}
```

and also without `AND Username = '".$user."'` i'm able to like all the tickets which are not in my account, but with it i'm just able to like my own tickets and not all shared tickets, i want to be able to like all the tickets.

**Whole code:** [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/63kepWWy)

Comment: From here it looks like the snippet _itself_ is executed 34 times, except if I'm missing something trivial here.

Comment: Is the ticket_id unique in that table?

Comment: @DavidSoussan No, the ticket_id is not unique i also want to do that.. i need to create array which will store the ID's, right ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about arry to store ids? Meanwhile, I'll bet that there are 34 rows with the same ticket_id, or there abouts. Just check how amny duplicates there are please.

Comment: @DavidSoussan nope there is no duplicate ticket_id, BTW i also want to make the ticket_id unique so to do that i need to make array to store the ticket_id number ?

Comment: NO. If the column already exists then you just need to add a unique index. Look in the manual if you don't know how to do that. Array have NOTHING to do with relational databases.

Comment: Print out your `$sql` and see if it's correct and works as expected in phpMyAdmin (or CLI).

Comment: @IkoTikashi Yup i just checked the sql, it works excellent :)

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code then, please?

Comment: @IkoTikashi http://pastebin.com/63kepWWy

Comment: Why is everybody talking about autoincrement and increment "gaps"? Am I missing something in the question or in one of the comments - is `liked` an autoincrement column? Even if `ticket_id` isn't unique I don't see why that would cause `SET liked=liked+1` to do anything other than increment that record by 1. I think the code is being called multiple times somehow.

Comment: @PeterBowers nope its not auto-increment column.. can i get into contact somehow with you please ? my skype is `stefanrafaa` email: `stefannrafa@gmail.com`

Comment: Run this query in phpMyAdmin: `SELECT ticket_id, count(*) FROM kladilnica GROUP BY ticket_id` and tell us the count results for the one you were trying to update.

Comment: When I looked at your code in the pastebin I see that you are looping through all records in kladilnica and for each one you are calling that `update` query, so it is true that if you had that many duplicates it would result in that many increments.

Comment: Move your `if`-block out of other `while`-loops or other `if`-blocks. @Stefan you might want to add the pastebin url to the complete code to your question, so everybody can easily find it.

Comment: @IkoTikashi Ohh thank you for this you have an great eye right there.. but now i have another problem with the `AND Username = '".$user."'` read up in the question.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question on that topic, it's already getting quite cramped in here.

Comment: Just a quick note: you'd need to check in your PHP if `$user` is allowed to like the specific ticket_id and only then run your update query (assuming that `$user` is the currently loggedin user). Adding "`AND Username = '".$user."`' to your query doesn't restrict anybody from updating.